# ReactJS: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined(…)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to build a timer with React and Redux.

I am separating concerns as much as possible.  Please help me find a working solution! Thank you.

Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined(…)

Timer Component

```
Timer.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import timer from '../reducers/index.js';
import store from '../stores/timerStore.js';


 // React Component to display the timer
 class Timer extends Component {
    constructor() {
     super();
     this.start = this.start.bind(this);
     this.stop = this.stop.bind(this);
    }

    start() {
      store.dispatch({
      type: 'START_TIMER',
      offset: Date.now(),
    });
   }
  stop() {
    store.dispatch({
    type: 'STOP_TIMER'
  });
 }
format(time) {
   const pad = (time, length) => {
     while (time.length < length) {
     time = '0' + time;
   }
  return time;
}

time = new Date(time);
let m = pad(time.getMinutes().toString(), 2);
let s = pad(time.getSeconds().toString(), 2);
let ms = pad(time.getMilliseconds().toString(), 3);

 return `${m} : ${s} . ${ms}`;
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Time: {this.format(this.props.time)}</h1>
      <button onClick={this.props.isOn ? this.stop : this.start}>
       { this.props.isOn ? 'Stop' : 'Start' }
      </button>
    </div>
   );
  }
}



export default Timer;
```

Timer Reducer

```
    timer.js

   // Initial state for reducer
   const initialState = {
      isOn: false,
      time: 0
    };


    function timer(state = initialState, action) {
       switch (action.type) {
          case 'START_TIMER':
            return {
             ...initialState,
             isOn: true,
             offset: action.offset,
             };

          case 'STOP_TIMER':
           return {
             isOn: false,
             time: state.time
            };

         case 'TICK':
           return {
            ...state,
            time: state.time + (action.time - state.offset),
            offset: action.time
          };

        default:
        return state;
      }
     }

   export default timer;
```

Timer Store

```
  timerStore.js

  import { createStore } from 'redux';
  import timer from '../reducers/index.js';

  // Create store using the reducer
  export const store = createStore(timer);
```

Main App Component

```
   index.js

   import React, { Component } from 'react';
   import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
   import Timer from './components/Timer.js';
   import store from './stores/timerStore.js';

   const render = () => {
      ReactDOM.render(
      <Timer
          time={store.getState().time}
          isOn={store.getState().isOn}
          interval={store.getState().interval}
       />,
      document.getElementById("app")
     );
    }

    store.subscribe(render);

    var interval = null;
     store.subscribe(() => {
       if (store.getState().isOn && interval === null) {
          interval = setInterval(() => {
           store.dispatch({
        type: 'TICK',
        time: Date.now()
       });
     });
     }
   if (!store.getState().isOn && interval !== null) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      interval = null;
     }
    });

  render();
```

Comment: Did you get a file and line number along with the error?

Answer (score 1):

You've got two different problems:

First, you're doing a "named export" of the store variable, but a "default import" of that file.  You need to make sure that the two match up.  Either do `export default createStore(timer)` and `import store from "./stores/timerStore"`, or do `export const store = createStore(timer)` and `import {store} from "./stores/timerStore"`.

Second, you really shouldn't be doing "manual" subscriptions to the store.  The React-Redux package provides a `connect` function, which generates container components that manage the subscription and update process for you.

As an additional observation, the folder named "stores" suggests that you're creating multiple Redux stores.  While you *can* do that, it's not a recommended approach.

**update**

And, looking at it, you've got a third problem: the `<Timer>` component won't re-render, because it doesn't know the store has updated.  It'll only ever use the initial values from the `ReactDOM.render(<Timer>)` call.

Per the comment I just wrote below, you should really write this as a couple different components.  One component should be connected to the Redux store and manage the timer logic with `setInterval`, and it should render another component that displays the timer info.

Comment: +1 Good eye on the first point. For the subscription which manages a timer, that makes sense using .subscribe directly, because it doesn't exist as part of a DOM component.

Comment: Actually, that seems like a great use for a couple "container" components.  The `connect` call would generate one container that accesses the Redux store, and the component passed to `connect` could itself be a "container"-type component that manages the interval and renders `<Timer>`.

Comment: Your update is incorrect. It will re-render. The render function is called everytime the state changes and fetches the current values of the state items.

Comment: Yes, you could have React component which manges the interval. I think this way is better, and the creator of redux agreed with me: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1194#issuecomment-233193780. This code was adapted from an example of how to do this that I posted in a github issue.

Comment: Ah, my bad, missed the `store.subscribe(render)`